# Making JSON calls to Unoffical Pandora API

Tags: json, api, url, pandora

So I was listening to Pandora at work, and was like, Man, it would be really cool to get the station list of Pandora, or interact with it remotely in some capacity..

So I found this unofficial Pandora API which just returns a bunch of JSON objects which look pretty helpful and neat! Here is the link to the API: http://pan-do-ra-api.wikia.com/wiki/Json/5

**The problem is** I have never really used JSON and definitely never used this API so I am not sure how to go about doing things. I think that if someone gave me an example of how to say get the station list from my windows 7 desktop computer that would be really helpful and I could probably get the rest from there.

Thanks!

Comment: Marc, I know this is kind of an open question, if you look at all my other ones, you will see I generally write very detailed questions and provide more answers than questions on a regular basis (not just Stack Overflow). I thought I could do it one time but I kind of anticipated a snarky comment like yours, but really I was just hoping that someone could chime in with a one liner like append "=login: username, encrpytedPassword" to your url, then follow that by user.getStationList, etc. 

My biggest question is how to put together the url, which the JSON website is not very helpful about.

Comment: And I am also not asking for 300 lines of code or to do my job, this was a for fun, spur of the moment question that I thought could be interesting to others as well.

Comment: That is an outdated link, you probably meant this [API](https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Again, with the comments from Marc B, I somewhat agree.  However, to more generically answer your question- it's probably not worth your time.

Pandora request / response bodies are all sent over HTTP/HTTPS.  However, they are all encrypted.  There is a "public" list of keys you can use to encrypt and decrypt the responses.  Once you have sorted all of that out, you'll have to use the APIs.

First you have to authenticate the user to get an Auth token.  From there, you can access the APIs which require the auth tokens.

To your final point, JSON interfaces work in lots of different ways.  Sometimes the API is specified through the URL itself like
http://example.com/json/foo

Other times, it's specified in the request body through a POST.

If you really want to figure this out, I would play with it.  I doubt anybody will post code on how to manipulate an API that isn't really "public".  Pandora changes it somewhat frequently to purposefully break third party applications.

A simple JSON example:

POST to http://example.com/json/foo

```
{ param: "val",
  anotherParam: "val",
  responseType: "XML" }
```

Response might look like

```
{ status: 200,
  result: "you called the foo API" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandora has a new [Developer Center](https://developer.pandora.com/), but access to the API is restricted and we do not currently support access for hobbyists. Nonetheless, if you think you have a valid use case, please feel free to apply for access. The more detail you can include on what you're trying to do, the better.

Comment: After filling out the partnership request form and clicking submit, I get this error msg: "CSRF Verification Failed, Your CSRF token is missing or invalid. Please reload the page or log in again with the button below." Using latest firefox. Any idea?