# Any tips on how i would go about extract Pandora likes and putting them on a spreadsheet? (C++/C#)

Tags: c#, html, c++, pandora

Fairly new to coding and i want a project to work on that could help me advance my skills. I'm not sure what language would be best for this sort of undertaking but i would definitely prefer to use C++ or C#.

For the first part of the program i basically would like to try and take all my pandora likes and put them on a spreadsheet with song name is one column and artist in the other. I don't see the formatting being too hard once i actually get the data i need, but i'm not really sure how to communicate with a server at all in this point in time. I'm guessing i probably won't be able to grab a raw list of likes so the i'm thinking my best course of action will be to first expand the likes list all the way, and then i need to read the text on the screen ro in the source code.

For the first step, expanding my like i found the HTML source code that actually does this:

```
<div class="show_more tracklike" data-nextLikeStartIndex="0" data-nextThumbStartIndex="5">Show more</div>"
```

Not sure if this is something i can work with but i was thinking if i could set data-nextThumbStartIndex="5" to be equal to the # of likes - 5 (the amount it shows by default) it would be fairly easy to expand the list. If not i would probably have to click the "show more" link repeatedly until i have all the likes on the page.

For the next step, getting the data i want, i think my best option would be to basically just grab the text that i physically see on the screen and worry about filtering and manipulating the data afterwards. The other option is looking at the source code, which i actually found the pieces of code where the info i want is stored. If i could retrieve the page's source code i think it would be relatively easy to pick out the data i actually want from that.

So yea that's about it, i know i'm pretty noob atm and what i'm saying is probably wrong and/or much more complicated than i think but i'm a pretty quick learner and at the very least if someone could point me in the right direction to communicate with a server that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quite "wide" (and I have absolutely no knowledge of Pandora itself - can't access it from where I live).

In general, there are several different ways to solve this type of problem:

1. Screen Scraping - basically access the website as if you were a web-server, and from the HTML string that comes back, dig out the information you need. The problem here is that the data is not very suitable for "machine reading", as it often has no distinct points for the "reader" to find the relevant information, and it's difficult to sort the data from the "chaff".
2. AJAX api - "Asynchronous Java Script and XML" where the provider of the website has an interface to fetch certain data within to the web-browser - of course, if you "pretend" to be the web-browser, requesting the same type of information. You are relying on the website to have such an interface, but if it exists, the data is generally in a "more suitable form to be machine read" (typically XML, but not always).
3. JSON api - "Java Script Object Notation" is a similar solution to AJAX - like XML, JSON is a "human and machine readable format".

The latter two are definitely preferable, as the data coming back is meant for machine reading. The drawback is that you need to have "server side cooperation". The good thing here is that Pandora does have a JSON API. The bad thing is that it seems to be hard to use... Here's one discussion on the subject:
[Making JSON calls to Unoffical Pandora API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049578/making-json-calls-to-unoffical-pandora-api)

The main principle here is that you send some stuff to the webserver, and receive a reply with the requested information. Exactly how this is done depends on the language/programming environment. A popular C++ solution is libcurl.

There is a Ruby Client here, using the JSON interface
https://github.com/nixme/pandora_client

A C# implementation to interface with Pandora is here:
http://pandoraunleashed.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PandoraUnleashed/Pandora.cs

Unfortunately, I can't find any direct reference to "listing likes".

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this will be a good place to start. Much appreciated.